# Retrieve output variable from MySQL stored procedure using CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, stored-procedures

I'm attempting to call a stored procedure using CakePHP.

Currently the returned values are comprised of the first recordset from the first SQL select statement in the stored procedure.

Even though the output variable is set in the stored procedure (ie. `select @project_id into project_id`), it doesn't show in the var_dump of the query result.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'admin'@'%'
PROCEDURE thebuggenie.cmdb_project_team_init(
  IN project_name VARCHAR(200), 
  IN project_key VARCHAR(200), 
  IN project_homepage VARCHAR(200), 
  IN team_name VARCHAR(200),
  OUT project_id INT(10))
BEGIN
  -- start transaction
  start transaction;

  -- init variables
  set @project_id = 0;
  set @team_id = 0;
  set @assoc_count = 0;
  set @scope_id = 1;

  -- select team and set variable
  select @team_id := id 
    from tbg3_teams 
    where name = team_name;

  -- if team_id = 0, insert team and set variable
  if @team_id is NULL or @team_id = '' or @team_id = 0 then
    -- insert new project
    insert into tbg3_teams(ondemand, name, scope) values(0, team_name, @scope_id);
    -- set team_id variable
    set @team_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  end if;

  -- select project and set variable
  select @project_id := id 
    from tbg3_projects 
    where name = project_name;

  -- if project_id = 0, insert project and set variable
  if @project_id is NULL or @project_id = '' or @project_id = 0 then
    -- insert project
    insert into tbg3_projects (name, locked, use_scrum, `key`, homepage, deleted, owner_team, scope, workflow_scheme_id, issuetype_scheme_id) values(project_name, 0, 1, project_key, project_homepage, 0, @team_id, @scope_id, 1, 1); 
    -- set project_id variable
    set @project_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  end if;

  select @assoc_count := count(*) 
    from tbg3_projectassignedteams 
    where uid = @team_id 
    and project_id = @project_id;

  if(@assoc_count = 0 and @project_id > 0 and @team_id > 0) then
    insert into tbg3_projectassignedteams (project_id, role_id, uid, scope) values(@project_id, 35, @team_id, @scope_id);
  end if;

  -- setup default views
  INSERT INTO tbg3_dashboard_views (name, view, pid, tid, target_type, scope) VALUES (101, 0, 0, @project_id, 2, 1);
  INSERT INTO tbg3_dashboard_views (name, view, pid, tid, target_type, scope) VALUES (102, 0, 0, @project_id, 2, 1);
  INSERT INTO tbg3_dashboard_views (name, view, pid, tid, target_type, scope) VALUES (110, 0, 0, @project_id, 2, 1);
  INSERT INTO tbg3_dashboard_views (name, view, pid, tid, target_type, scope) VALUES (105, 0, 0, @project_id, 2, 1);
  INSERT INTO tbg3_dashboard_views (name, view, pid, tid, target_type, scope) VALUES (106, 0, 0, @project_id, 2, 1);
  INSERT INTO tbg3_dashboard_views (name, view, pid, tid, target_type, scope) VALUES (111, 0, 0, @project_id, 2, 1);

  commit;

  -- return values
  select @project_id INTO project_id;
END
```

PHP Code:

```
$sql = "call thebuggenie.cmdb_project_team_init(";
$sql .= '\''.$results[0]['Asset']['project_name'].'\'';
$sql .= ',\''.$results[0]['Asset']['project_name'].'\'';
$sql .= ',\'\'';
$sql .= ',\''.$results[0]['Repository']['team_name'].'\'';
$sql .= ',@project_id';
$sql .= ');';
$sql .= 'select @project_id as project_id';

var_dump($sql);

$results = $this->Asset->query($sql);

print_r($results);
```

PHP Code outputs:

```
string 'call thebuggenie.cmdb_project_team_init('CMDB','CMDB','','team-app-platforms',@project_id);select @project_id as project_id;'

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [@team_id := id] => 6 ) ) )
```

Note: I haven't finalized error trapping yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this:

```
$sql = "call thebuggenie.cmdb_project_team_init(";
$sql .= '\''.$results[0]['Asset']['project_name'].'\'';
$sql .= ',\''.$results[0]['Asset']['project_name'].'\'';
$sql .= ',\'\'';
$sql .= ',\''.$results[0]['Repository']['team_name'].'\'';
$sql .= ',@project_id';
$sql .= '); select @project_id as project_id';

var_dump($sql);

$mysqli = new mysqli("DB_HOST", "DB_USER", "DB_PWD", "DATABASE");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$out = array();

if($mysqli->multi_query($sql))
 { 
    do
    {

        if($result=$mysqli->store_result())
        {
            while($row=$result->fetch_row())
            {
                array_push($out, $row);
            }
            $result->free();
        }

    }while($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
 }


$mysqli->close();
```

$out[3][0] contained the value I was looking for.